# Scala method definition named parameters vs. unnamed

Tags: scala, methods, signature

i'm new to Scala and i'm struggling sometimes with method signatures.
Lets take this code, i'm especially interested in naming the parameters to do further operations on them.

```
def divide(xs: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
      val mid = xs.length/2
      (xs take mid, xs drop mid)
}
```

Here I defined the input list named as "xs", I've seen this convention on many web pages. But in university we had another method signature definition method (I am missing the name, sorry) in which we didn't name the input parameter(s) but pattern matching takes place:

```
   def mylength: List[Any] => Int = {
     case Nil   => 0
     case x::xs => mylength(xs)+1
   }
```

In this case, it is very trivial to identify the input parameter because there is just a single one. How could I use the same style as in the code below with 2 or more input parameters in the coding style shown above?

```
   def myConcat(xs: List[Any], ys: List[Any]) = {
              xs ++ ys
   }
```

Sorry for my English. I didn't find anything on google because I didn't relly have a clue what terms to search for...

Edit: I have to stick to an interface. I make another example with which you could help me.
myAppend1 and myAppend2 shall behave the same way, putting a new element in the front of the list.

```
   def myAppend1(xs: List[Any], y: Any): List[Any] = {
        y :: xs
   }
```

My problem is now the naming of my inputs in myAppend2...

```
  def myAppend2: List[Any] => Any => List[Any] = {
           /* how can i do this here, when no names y/xs are given?*/
   }
```

Comment: `mylength` takes no parameters, but returns a function that takes a list parameter, where as `myConcat` takes two parameters.  See for example, http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Function1, about function types.  This may help your googling.  I am sure someone will come along to answer your question, if not I will do it when I have more time later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def myAppend2: List[Any] => Any => List[Any] = { xs => y => 
    y :: xs
}
```

with full form of function literal syntax:

```
def myAppend2: List[Any] => Any => List[Any] = {
    (xs: List[Any]) => {
        (y: Any) => {
            y :: xs
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To use the same style with 2 or more parameters, just treat the parameters as a tuple of two:

```
 def myConcat: (List[Any], List[Any]) => List[Any] = { 
   case (Nil, Nil) => List()
   case (xs,ys) => ... 
 }
```

Let's take the `myAppend` example:

```
 def myAppend2: (List[Any], Any) => List[Any] = {
    case (xs, y) => y :: xs 
 }
```

This has (more or less) the same signature as:

```
def myAppend1(xs: List[Any], y: Any): List[Any] = {
    y :: xs
}
```

Usage:

```
scala> myAppend1(List(1,2,3), 4)
res3: List[Any] = List(4, 1, 2, 3)

scala> myAppend2(List(1,2,3), 4)
res4: List[Any] = List(4, 1, 2, 3)
```

If you had a higher-order function that wanted a function argument of `(List[Any], Any) = List[Any]`, then both will work and are (for most practical purposes) equivalent.

Note that by defining it like

```
def myAppend3: List[Any] => Any => List[Any] = {
   xs => y => y::xs
}
```

you will be creating a curried function, which in scala has a different signature 
(from what you want):

```
 myAppend3(List(1,2,3), 4) // won't compile
 myAppend3(List(1,2,3))(4) // need to do this
```

Comment: I'm not allowed to alter the signature ;( Of course this would be easier, but 'pure functionality' is not the goal for me atm.

Comment: But if there is no option to do it otherwise - nice solution.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Appreciate it very much!